# Can I set a default Y range in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

My graphs will be generated based on runtime data, such as user-provided time ranges. I can't know ahead of time whether data within the requested `xrange` will actually exist.

In the case that it's not, I'd like to show a blank plot (with X=time range as requested, but arbitrary Y scale) rather than having to handle an error message *"all points y value undefined!"*.

I've read that it's possible to run `stats` (in gnuplot 4.6) or its gnuplot 4.4 equivalent of running `plot` with `set term unknown` to collect stats, then manually set up a range before plotting properly.

However, I'm concerned about effectively running `plot` twice over a ~200MB ASCII input, and it seems wasteful to scan the entire file like that just to determine an Y range when I don't actually need any particular Y range in the case that my `set xrange` directive doesn't encompass any datapoints.

**Is it possible to persuade gnuplot to just quietly accept a lack of datapoints and show me an empty graph, without iterating over the data any more than I already do?**

Comment: Surprised I couldn't find this asked before!

Comment: @Christoph: Ok np if that's the answer you can post it as such and I'd accept =)

Comment: BTW: Could you please correct "GNUPlot" to "gnuplot"? The program has nothing to do with GNU, its name is just a [transcription of "newplot"](http://www.gnuplot.info/faq/faq.html#x1-70001.2), which aready existed as other program :)

Comment: @Christoph: Whoops yeah np

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message arises from the autoscaling. Only if you set a fixed yrange you can plot an empty graph. As example consider

```
plot 1/0
```

which gives the same error message `all points y value undefined!`, whereas the commands

```
plot [][0:1] 1/0
```

generates an empty graph.

And no, gnuplot doesn't have any sort of default yrange which is used when autoscaling fails (also not in version 5.0). I guess it is not gnuplot's workspace, to *automatically* handle wrong user input and display an empty graph no matter what invalid input it got.

Comment: The workaround looks promising but alas gnuplot 4.4 seems to stop immediately after the failed plot with exit code 1. This is with the commands fed in in a script. Praps I'll just have to re-invoke gnuplot to show an empty graph (which is probably fine)

Comment: Yes, now I see, that this doesn't work neither with 4.6.3. The script stops at the first failing plot command.